# randomize selection and output variable to span tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code:

```
var doNewPoll = function(){
  var vacationIndex = Math.round(Math.random(myVacations.length));
  var dest1 = myVacations[vacationIndex];
  var dest2 = myVacations[vacationIndex];
  alert(dest1);
  alert(dest2);
  }
```

My 2 questions are: 
1) How do I make sure my variables dest1 and dest2 are not the same? I want it to pull 2 different options from the myVacations array.
and 2) I can get the alerts to work, but instead of an alert, I want the results for dest1 and dest2 to appear in the document in span tags id'd Span1 and Span2. I'm just having a brain fart on how to do that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, use floor, not round, you don't want your index to be the length :

```
 Math.floor(Math.random(myVacations.length));
```

Then, the easiest to avoid duplicate is just to loop until the second number is different from the first. This means you must build another index, of course :

```
var index1 = Math.floor(Math.random(myVacations.length));
var index2 = index1;
while (index2==index1) index2 = Math.floor(Math.random(myVacations.length));
var dest1 = myVacations[index1];
var dest2 = myVacations[index2];
```

To make the document appear in span, the simplest is to start with the elements yet present :

```
<span id=d1></span>
<span id=d2></span>
```

And then to fill them :

```
document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = dest1;
document.getElementById("d2").innerHTML = dest2;
```

Comment: Also, since the index is stored in a variable, `dest1` and `dest2` should always be the same assuming `myVacations` doesn't change between those lines. So you'll need two `Math.floor(Math.random(myVacations.length));` lines.

Comment: @dystroy I updated my code with your suggestions, and now I can't preview the page in my browser - it just spins and spins and never loads. Any ideas? The doNewPoll function is set to run onload, so is it getting stuck in the loop somehow?

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, I couldn't get this method to work, so I ended up going with a completely different method.

Answer (score 0):

// I assume span1 and span2 are the id of those elements

```
var doNewPoll = function(myVacations, span1, span2){
  var vacationIndex1 = Math.round(Math.random(myVacations.length));
  var vacationIndex2 = null; 
  do{ 
     vacationIndex2 = Math.round(Math.random(myVacations.length)); 
  } while (vacationIndex2 == vacationIndex); 

  document.getElementById(span1).innerHTML = myVacations[vacationIndex1]; 
  document.getElementById(span2).innerHTML = myVacations[vacationIndex2]; 

}
```